# Doctrine shopping cart after add order: undefined index

Tags: php, session, doctrine-orm, nette

I program shopping cart in Doctrine and Nette Framework.
There is `addItem` method: (add to session cart)

```
public function addItem($item) {
    $cart = $this->getCartSection();
    $product = $this->product_facade->getProduct($item['voucher_id']);

    if (isset($cart->cart_items[$product->getId()])) {
        $cart->cart_items[$product->getId()]['amount'] += $item['amount'];
    } else {
        $cart->cart_items[$product->getId()] = array(
            'voucher' => $product,
            'amount' => $item['amount']
        );
    }
}
```

And there is a method for add order to db

```
public function add($creator, $data) {    
    $order = new Orders();
    $order->setPrice($data['price']);
    $order->setStatus($this->status_facade->getStatus(self::NEW_STATUS_ID));
    $order->setPayment($this->payment_facade->getPayment($data->payment));
    $order->setDate(new DateTime());
    $order->setUser($creator);

foreach ($data['cart'] as $item) {      
      $order_product = new OrdersProduct();
      $order_product->setQuantity($item['amount']);
      $order_product->setProduct($item['voucher']);

      $order->addItem($order_product);
    }

    $this->em->persist($order);
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

I get error after click to button 'add to order'

```
Undefined index: 00000000659576f8000000004032b93e
```

But I know where is a error. There is a method `add` and this method gets Product entity from session.

```
$order_product->setProduct($item['voucher']);
```

I need product entity in session becuase I want count total price in cart.
If I call in add method `setProduct` with number or `$item['voucher']->getId()` (this variable is entity from `Product`)

```
$order_product->setProduct(
  $this->product_facade->getProduct(4)
);
```

It's OK, but I don't know, why I call product entity from session is wronk. This is same method with same result.

Can you help me with problem? Do you know why is wronk?

Thank you, I hope You understand me.

Comment: OK, It is wrong thing save entity to session. In the session serialization objects. I must save only ID to session.

Answer (score 1):

You can't save entities into session. Doctrine uses [Identity Map](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork.html).

Save only entity ID to session and read the entity from database before working with it. If you need more data in session, don't use entity for that. Reather implement [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object).

Comment: Yes I know now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can store an entity in a session. You can read more in Doctrine docs:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/entities-in-session.html

When retrieving an entity from a session you need to call `merge` on your `EntityManager`

```
$entity = $this->em->merge($entityFromSession);
```